# Postman isn't capturing/setting cookie from 127.0.0.1

Tags: postman

I'm running my api locally and it's not capturing/setting the cookie. The curl call in fact does have the cookie `Set-Cookie: auth=....` in the response headers... Any thoughts? I have also tried localhost (which I actually would expect to not work).